# Browsing laptop models by display resolution

Tags: laptop, hardware-rec

To put it shortly, is there a place where one could browse laptop models of different manufacturers, by screen resolution.

(I have some software which depends on display resolution, and therefore need a laptop with either 1400x1050 or from that line)

Answer (score 1):

The Dutch website tweakers.net supports this in their [PriceWatch register](http://tweakers.net/pricewatch/cat/496/laptops.html#filter:NYsxDsIwEAT_cnWKQAxCfkAkClcpEYWxV8KSwdHZCaDIf-dSuFrdzNxG0f7SUkzyIE3lubwe1FFiDx4Dohe4Bnxyg1PiIswjO0EzBwcT3qT7jrJLDGO_pE_taAYRrsBPM9zVZ9I3Ol7kfaC7SIFjiAUsYqPh3O-z2rhnB6WUhDLS1lr_) (which is actually quite complete).

Comment: Yes. Unfortunatelly, their catalog is somewhat limited, since I know for a fact of several others which support the aforementioned resolution. But, a nice link, nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter by screen resolution on Newegg (Advanced Search): http://www.newegg.com/Store/SubCategory.aspx?SubCategory=32&name=Laptops-Notebooks